# ScrollBar - Calcular campo de movimento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como calcular o campo de movimento da div da scrollbar nesse caso:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/2/)**

```
var margem = 0;
function criarBarraDeRolagem(){
if ($( document ).height() < $( window ).height()) 
{
return; 
}
var tamanho = $( window ).height() / $( document ).height();
$('#rolagem2').css('top', margem + ($( window ).scrollTop() * tamanho));
$('#rolagem2').height($( window ).height() * tamanho - (margem + margem) );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
criarBarraDeRolagem();
});



var dragObj = null;
$("#rolagem2, body, html").mouseup(function(){
$('body, html').removeClass("unselectable");
dragObj = null;
});

$("#rolagem2").mousedown(function(){
$('body, html').addClass("unselectable");
dragObj = this;
});

$("#rolagem2, body, html").mousemove(function(e){
if( dragObj ) 
{
var move = e.pageY - $("#rolagem").offset().top;
$(window).scrollTop(move * 4); // O PROBLEMA ESTÁ AQUI
criarBarraDeRolagem();
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
}   
});
```

**O script funciona, só que se aumentar o tamanho do body ele fica igual no jsfiddle...**

Fiz um comentário na parte do script que precisa alterar...

Comment: Não entendi o real problema, é a questão de não conseguir levar a barra de rolagem até no final?

Comment: @luigibertaco, exatamente!!!

Comment: Eu coloquei `11.5` e ela vai até o final... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/3/)

Comment: @KaduAmaral, mas caso eu diminua o body ele buga...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta calcular a velocidade dividindo o tamanho da tela pelo tamanho da tua barra, ou algo parecido. Eu não identifiquei muitos problemas aqui, mas não estou tão por dentro do teu projeto, mas coloquei ali uma **variável speed** e também coloquei pra **atualizar a barra quando a janela for redimensionada**.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qq27jan/4/)

Uma sugestão de melhoria seria colocar pra ignorar a posição do cursor sobre a barra de rolagem, subtraindo a posição da barra pela posição do mouse e ignorando essa diferença, mas não estou com tanto tempo agora pra ver isso.

Comment: Quando puder me ajuda nessa sugestão de ignorar a posição do cursor sobre a barra de rolagem!!!

Comment: Beleza, quando tiver um tempinho eu vejo o que consigo aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei as linhas:

```
$('#rolagem2').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
```

E

```
if (move < $(window).height() - $('#rolagem2').height()){
```

Ficou assim

```
var margem = 0;

function criarBarraDeRolagem() {
    if ($(document).height() < $(window).height()) {
        return;
    }
    var tamanho = $(window).height() / $(document).height();
    $('#rolagem2').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    $('#rolagem2').height($(window).height() * tamanho - (margem + margem));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    criarBarraDeRolagem();
});



var dragObj = null;
$("#rolagem2, body, html").mouseup(function () {
    $('body, html').removeClass("unselectable");
    dragObj = null;
});

$("#rolagem2").mousedown(function () {
    $('body, html').addClass("unselectable");
    dragObj = this;
});

$("#rolagem2, body, html").mousemove(function (e) {
    if (dragObj) {
        var move = e.pageY - $("#rolagem").offset().top;
        if (move < $(window).height() - $('#rolagem2').height()){
            $(window).scrollTop(move); // O PROBLEMA ESTÁ AQUI
            criarBarraDeRolagem();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```